# Upload files to sharepoint using an email

Tags: email, sharepoint, slack, power-automate, data-transfer

Is it possible to send email to a sharepoint folder similar to sending messages in slack channel via email?

I want to be able to upload csv files to a sharepoint folder by sending email attachments to automate our data transfer workflows.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-incoming-e-mail-support-for-a-list-or-library-dcaf44a0-1d9b-451a-84c7-6c52e7db908e

Comment: Yes, it’s possible.